# xpath getting node value by attribute equals another node's value

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm an XPath novice and I have the following xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <colors>
    <color id="1">green</color>
    <color id="2">red</color>
    <color id="3">yellow</color>
  </colors>
  <items>
    <item id="095">
       <title>pencil</title>
      <colorId>3</colorId>
    </item>
    <item id="100">
      <title>pen</title>
      <colorId>1</colorId>
    </item>
    <item id="200">
      <title>ruler</title>
      <colorId>2</colorId>
    </item>
  </items>
</catalog>`
```

As you can see, colorId values correspond to the color id attributes, so "pencil" is "yellow" (3), "pen" is "green" (1) and "ruler" is "red" (2).
The question is how do I get  value for each item via colorId value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return the `title` based on the `id`:

```
/catalog/items/item[colorId = /catalog/colors/color/@id]/title
```

This will return the `color` corresponding to the `colorId`:

```
/catalog/colors/color[@id = /catalog/items/item/colorId]
```

You can then add position predicates to select specific relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question -- that you want to look for `<item>`s that are a specific color -- what you're looking for is XPath [Predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates). For example:

```
/catalog/items/item[colorId=2]
```

will find the s whose  child's contents equal 2.